# Getting compilation error for CATIA V5 R30 CAA build

Tags: compilation, catia, caa

I am looking for help on CATIA V5 R30 CAA help. I am getting the below error.
C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B30.\BSFBuildtimeData\PublicInterfaces\CATIAV5Precompiled.h(47): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wtypes.h': No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons you are getting this error:

1. CAA RADE is not installed correctly. Try Check integrity from the Software Management. It will give any error if any RADE component is missing.
2. Missing some dependence missing from your machine. Try to build your CAA workspace using the tck batches. It will show any missing dependencies in step 3, 4 or 5:

   cd "Target WS"
   call "TCK_INIT.BAT" - ie. "C:\Program Files (x86)\DASSAULT SYSTEMES\B215\intel_a\code\command\TCK_INIT.BAT"
   call tck_profile "CATIA Version"    - i.e V6R2014_B215
   call mkgetpreq -p "DS install path" - i.e "c:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B215"
   call mkmk -W %TARGET WS% -a

Mostly, you have missing JDK or windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

the platform should be **win10**+vs2017, not win7+vs2017

Comment: Thank You. Actually, the issue was in windows SDK. I installed the latest SDK and it works.